# jump to a directory inside of ranger

Tags: ranger

I tried `:cd path` but it does literally nothing.

Imagine I open ranger while inside of `~/dir/`, now I want to go to `~/somewhere/else/` while inside of ranger.

I know I can `hjjjj(whatever)lj/k(whatever)l` to move from folder-to-folder while inside ranger, but I want to jump directly to `~/somewhere/else/`.

How do I do that?

Comment: :cd works for me if the path exists. did you update to the latest version?

Comment: @laktak I am on 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in two ways:

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
   It opens a new shell on the current directory.

   Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to go back to `ranger`.
2. Use `source ranger` command.

   When you hit `q`, you will close ranger by jumping into the directory. You can also add an alias this command in `.bashrc` file.

   ```
   alias ranger="source ranger"
   ```

   and call it as `ranger`